# UTF-8 characters displaying as junk values

Tags: java, javascript, sql, database

We use SQL navigator as database to store our data for the fields.

But if we try to store UTF-8 characters it is stored as some junk value and that only gets displayed in our application.

Can some one help regarding this problem as to why junk values are displayed.

Comment: Without code nobody can help you. Please [edit] your question and add the relevant parts + an actual data example.

Comment: Hi, actually the problem is that only one dialog box which appears shows the junk symbols for the utf 8 charcters but the rest screens are fine.. only one has the problem. so wat could be the resons behind it.. its a jsp page.. and i have a statement                                                      <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %> still it doesnt hsow the correct utf 8 charcter

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your db / table / field collations (should be ci_utf8_general or equivalent)
2. when connecting to DB in your app, use this query `SET NAMES utf8` after opening connection.

Hope it will solve your utf8 char problems and store them in DB with right char encoding.